# To insert datepicker date to sql server

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql-server, datepicker, date-format

I want to insert a date from datepicker to sql server.The table is as below :

```
Create table testDate
(
EventStart date,
EventEnd date
)

Create proc sptestdate
@EventStart date,
@EventEnd date
as
begin
Insert into testDate(EventStart,EventEnd) values(@EventStart,@EventEnd)
end
```

and the datepicker is as below :

```
 <script>
    $(function () {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
        });
    });
</script>
```

I do this using the below code-behind:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ss"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sptestdate", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventStart", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = txtEventStart.Value;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventEnd", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = txtEventEnd.Value;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

However, it throws an error

```
  "Error converting data type nvarchar to date."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `DateTime` object to your DB rather than passing a `String` (Textbox.Text returns String), you can use [DateTime.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) :-

```
DateTime.Parse(txtEventStart.Value);
DateTime.Parse(txtEventEnd.Value);
```

You can also use [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: SET DATEFORMAT for database https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx

Comment: @MukeshPanwar - You can convert the date using `Convert` method of SQL.

Comment: Surprisingly, it has again started giving me an error message 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.' @RahulSingh

Comment: @MukeshPanwar - That means the date stored in textbox is not in correct format, even to parse the date it should be in correct format.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime result;
result = DateTime.ParseExact("your_date", format, provider);
```

This will solve your problem.